# Simple reading from terminal with CL

Tags: io, terminal, common-lisp

I'm a student and fairly new to Common Lisp. Up until now I have only written applications that perform calculations on natural language, reading from a text file corpus. Now I'm trying to understand how IO with the terminal works in CL. For this purpose I'm attempting to write a super simple application which takes an input from the user, and prints it back to screen. This is what I have:

```
(defun main ()
  (with-open-stream stream *terminal-io* :direction :output)
    (print (read-line stream nil)))
```

However this gives me an error saying that I need to use *BREAK ON SIGNALS*, which I do not how to do. Can you help me understand what is wrong with my code (and why)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are trying to read from a stream, which you have opened for OUTPUT...? But the syntax is all wrong in the `with-open-stream` form, too. It's also unclear why you want to open a stream. Typically the `*terminal-io*` stream is already open. You can use it directly... there is no need to open a stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put it simply:

- You read from standard input using `read-line` and friends, generally without additional arguments.  Thus, `(read-line)` returns a line from stdin.  Beware of `read`, it is a security breach.
- You write to standard output using `write-line` and friends without additional arguments, as well as `(format t ...)`.
- When you want to set up a dialogue between the user and the program, you don't use standard input and output, but rather `*query-io*` supplying it as an optional argument for `read-line`, `write-line`, etc.  Mind that the output can be buffered, so in portable code you should perform `(finish-output *query-io*)` or `(force-output *query-io*)` to flush the output before the expected user input.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you may want also to do shell scripting with common lisp in this case you will need the shebang linedepending on your lisp implementation, I usually use SBCL with slimen here you have a table:

http://www.cliki.net/Unix%20shell%20scripting

Then I think that since you are a student and you want to learn I recommend you to inspect asdf and uiop, imported as an extension in sbcl, take a look at this articles:

[Why Lisp is Now an Acceptable Scripting Language](http://fare.tunes.org/files/asdf3/asdf3-2014.html)

With this I write this script that show this a sample,for the future also explore uiop:run-program ;-), and use the different streams *standard-input* and *terminal-io*, you should also take a look on common lisp streams

```
#!/usr/bin/sbcl --script

(require :uiop)

;;reading comman line arguments
(dolist (element uiop:*command-line-arguments*)
  (uiop:writeln element)
  (write-line element));; look the different output

;; for printing strings on *standard-output*
(write-line "Hi this is a sample script")
(format t "~A ~A ~A ~B ~%" "what you want even a number like" 2 "in binary" 2 )

;; now let's read other arguments
(write-line "please write some thing")

(defparameter line (read-line))

(write-line "you write a:")

(format t "~A" (type-of line))
(write-line "and this contents: ")
(write-line line)

;; now lets use *terminal-io*
(write-line "please introduce another thing" *terminal-io*)

(defparameter line (read-line))

(write-line "you write a:")

(format *terminal-io* "~A" (type-of line))
(write-line "and this contents: ")
(write-line line *terminal-io*)
```

when I execute it:

```
╭─anquegi@toshiba-debian  ~/learn/lisp/StackOverFlow ‹ruby-2.2.1@laguna› 
╰─$ ./fromterminal.lisp a b c                                                                                                                   148 ↵
"a"
a
"b"
b
"c"
c
Hi this is a sample script
what you want even a number like 2 in binary 10 
please write some thing
calimero
you write a:
(SIMPLE-ARRAY CHARACTER (8))and this contents: 
calimero
please introduce another thing
pato
you write a:
(SIMPLE-ARRAY CHARACTER (4))and this contents: 
pato
```

there are more examples for using common lisp as a shell script, like this:

[learn common lisp with shell scripts](http://www.xhbml.com/archives/37), but I recommend you to explore and lear sbcl, asdf and uiop, good luck

Comment: Such a great and patient answer.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read input from the CLI you can use [`*query-io*`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_debug_.htm)* stream.

```
(read *query-io*)
```

keep in mind `read` uses the lisp reader, which can be an advantage. If you want to read general text you should use `read-line` instead.

*: I'm unsure of the difference between *terminal-io* and *query-io* and if they are interchangeable in this context.